# How to disable a rule for a variable

Tags: sonarqube, sonarjs

I am a new user of sonarQube. I installed the 6.3 version and analyzed old projects that we use in our group.
We have a variable named `ourProduct` that is existing in all the projects (and we will still used for future projects.

But when I analyze the projects on my local machine, I get this error

> "ourProduct" does not exist. Change its name or declare it so that its usage doesn't result in a "ReferenceError".

Is there a solution to disable this rule for this variable for all the projects (previous and future ones)?

Should I make an exclusion for this variable or write a new rule? And how do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to **Administration > JavaScript > Global variables** and add `ourProduct` to the list of global variables. That tells the SonarJS analyzer that `ourProduct` *is* defined but the definition is outside the current file.

Comment: thank you so much, it solved the problem! Nevertheless, It raised an other issue related to the rule "Lines should have sufficient coverage by tests" in the code blocks where I have my variable.
Does this mean that those blocks will never be covered by the tests for all the rules in sonarQube ?